# Will not install. Any ideas?

Tags: software-installation

I have a  laptop with Win10(Barebones).  Downloaded Ubuntu and copied to a flash drive.  I cannot get it to install.

Comment: It does not work to simply copy the iso file to a flash drive. You need at tool for it, for example Rufus. Install [**Rufus**](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) into Windows. Start by checking the iso file with md5sum, that it matches the listed string at [Ubuntuhashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes). Then you  use Rufus to make the flash drive bootable with Ubuntu. -- The next/other thing to do is to make the computer try to boot from USB. There is probably a hotkey to get a temporary boot menu. Otherwise you can go into the UEFI/BIOS menus and change the boot order.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information, it's difficult to guide you. You need to let us know what you've tried so far at the very least.

A typical Ubuntu installation from Windows is as follows:

1. Download the Ubuntu .ISO file. This will be found at the [Ubuntu website](https://www.ubuntu.com/).
2. Use a tool such as [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create a bootable flash drive write the ISO contents to
3. Keeping your flash drive inserted, restart your computer and enter the BIOS/UEFI setup. The key you need to press will depend on your computer, but it will typically be F2 or Del. The required key will be shown immediately after restarting/turning on your computer
4. Find the boot order menu and rearrange the entries so that your flash drive is the first to boot
5. Save and quit. Your computer will restart again
6. During the boot process, you should be prompted to try or install Ubuntu. You can follow the prompts from here on out.

If instead you are having issues with the actual installation process, again, please provide additional information. What stage of the installation are you at, what is the specific option or error you have trouble with, and what have you tried?